# Logic gates. BCD Multiplication. Karnaugh maps (I think)

Tags: digital-logic, karnaugh-map, logic-gates

I have to draw minimum combination of logic gates that multiply any BCD number with a 7. Output is also in BCD. It probably has something to do with Karnaugh maps, that's how we do this sort of problems in class. I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Start by building a truth table: BCD is a 4-bit input, so you have 4 inputs. Then next to each input value you write down what the output bits would look like. 7*9 = 63. so you probably want 2*4 bits as output. So a table listing the inputs digit, b3, b2, b1, b0 and the output (digit * 7), b13, b12, b11, b10, b03, b02, b01, b00. Where the digit is just for readability, b1x is the high digit at the output and b0x is the low digit in the output.

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly, the thing that has been stopping me is that BCD number can have 4,8,12... digits, right?

Comment: @Desperado : If you have more than 1 digit in the source operand, you will need an adder for all the partial products. You can start with a adder taking two 4bits inputs and a carry, then cascade the adders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Truth Table for BCD number which has to multiply by 7 and output too in BCD can be given as below

[image]

K-Map can be given as
[image]